# Passing variables with parameters through Javascript: What undefined means

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameters, parameter-passing

Here I am trying to pass `foo` into another function. `foo` is defined as an array as strings. Here is how it looks when displayed:

`foo = 2,4,"Party--12:00",2,22,"Eventalist Launch--6:00",2,18,"Play Day--12:00"`

Since I am only passing 1 variable, `pp and dd` are undefined and are nothing.

```
if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) 
                {
                    var xmlResponse = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseXML;
                    var foo = parseXML(xmlResponse);
                    //var string = JSON.stringify(foo);
                    dataOutput.innerHTML += foo;

                    getHoliday(pp,dd,foo);

                }
```

I am trying to pass the variable to my calendar function but I'm scratching my head because the variable becomes undefined here. What's the deal with this? I have variable `event` my array of strings, but it shows up as undefined. Am I confusing `HolidayName= new Array()` when `foo` already has passed an array to `HolidayName`?

```
function getHoliday(monthSelected,theday,names)
    {   
        var events = names;
        monthSelected = monthSelected + 1
        var holiday = ""
        var HolidayName = new Array(event);
}
```

Event ends up with no data, undefined if I did `HolidayName = events`

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what you're talking about, mostly because of your lack of conventional terminology. Which book are you using?

Comment: My description may be a little shallow, but what I mean is I want to know why, when i pass my variable `foo` from `getHoliday()` ends up to becomming undefined when the script reaches the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you assign the value to a variable named `events`:

```
var events = names;
```

Here you are trying to use the variable, but under the name `event`:

```
var HolidayName = new Array(event);
```